# Deluge Windows Service

Tags: web, service, torrent

I am trying to run the DelugeD.exe as a windows service. After installing Deluge and creating the services using NSSM, I try to start the service and get the following error:

> Windows could not start the Deluged service on Local Computer. The service did not return an error.  This could be and internal Windows error or and internal service error. If the problem persists, contact your system administrator.

[image]

I have created the Deluge-web-debug.exe as a Windows Service and it successfully starts.  When I browse to http://localhost:8112 the web client appears, however the **Connection Manager** shows the Deluged daemon has not started.

No error, no logs, what could be the cause?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I thought I would start from scratch, reinstall deluge for windows, and try again.  After this it still failed.

Using nssm, the error was:

> deluged: Unexpected status SERVICE_PAUSED in response to START control.

This placed the service in a perpetual Paused state.

Finally, I decided to tear down the services using nssm remove, kill any running deluge processes, then delete the Config folder where deluged was pointing.

I am certain deleting the Config folder and all files was what solved the problem, and now it starts successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I *think* I just solved this one by checking the "Allow service to interact with desktop" box under the LogOn tab for both the Deluge daemon and the WebUI services I created with nssm:

["Allow service to interact with desktop" in services.msc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1rSPw.png)